# hql CASE WHEN not able to use multiple time

Tags: mysql, spring, hql

I need to condition for order by in hql query.

1. sortBy(column name)
2. sortOrder (asc or desc)

In my hql query there are 3 tables joining

```
select a from TableA a, TableB b, TableC c WHERE a.column1 = b.column2 AND b.column1 = c.column2 ORDER BY CASE WHEN :sortBy = column3 THEN a.column3 WHEN :sortBy = column4 THEN b.column4 ELSE c.column5 END CASE WHEN :sortOrder = 'asc' THEN asc ELSE desc END
```

In this query, I got an error this Second `CASE WHEN` condition

I also tried by below query

```
select a from TableA a, TableB b, TableC c WHERE a.column1 = b.column2 AND b.column1 = c.column2 ORDER BY CASE WHEN :sortBy = column3 THEN (CASE WHEN :sortOrder = 'asc' THEN 'a.column3 asc' ELSE 'a.column3 desc' END) WHEN :sortBy = column4 THEN (CASE WHEN :sortOrder = 'asc' THEN 'b.column4 asc' ELSE 'b.column4 desc' END) ELSE (CASE WHEN :sortOrder = 'asc' THEN 'c.column5 asc' ELSE 'c.column5 desc' END) END
```

In this query response is not in ordering

can you please guide me what is wrong in this query?

Comment: The `CASE` expressions in your `ORDER BY` clause need to be separated by a comma.  This is a typo question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen there is no need to put comma in `ORDER BY`

Comment: You _do_ need a comma between the 2 `CASE` expressions, but actually I think the order by logic needs to be rewritten.

Comment: If you don't add sample data, it is unlikely anyone here will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause need to be separated by a comma.  However, it seems you want to be able to choose sort direction based on the parameter `:sortOrder`.  One approach would be to multiply with a `CASE` expression which generates `1.0` for ascending, and `-1.0` for descending.

```sql
SELECT a from TableA a, TableB b, TableC c
WHERE a.column1 = b.column2 AND b.column1 = c.column2
ORDER BY
    (CASE WHEN :sortOrder = 'asc' THEN 1.0 ELSE -1.0 END) *
    CASE WHEN :sortBy = column3 THEN a.column3
         WHEN :sortBy = column4 THEN b.column4
         ELSE c.column5 END;
```

Comment: @AkashChavda What are the _types_ of column 3, 4, and 5?  Please include that, along with some sample data, in your question above.

Comment: column5 is double and other two are string data type. And about that tables and data are too long

Comment: You can't do that.  _All_ branches of a `CASE` expression must have the same type.  Even if it might compile and run, the behavior you get probably won't be what you want.  Try adding some sample data to your question for best results here.

Comment: yes case expression comparision value are string but in THEN condition column types are different